# Пунктуация: "всё, как всегда" или "всё как всегда"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Всё, как всегда" или "Всё как всегда"?
(без контекста, это отдельное предложение)

Answer (score 4):

Без контекста совсем — не бывает. Контекст это не только — и даже не столько — слова по тексту вокруг и около фразы, это прежде всего обстановка, ситуация, в которой она сказана. Здесь это важно, без контекста — никак.

Оба варианта в принципе законны. Зависит от смысла, т. е. неправильная пунктуация изменит понимание фразы. Хотя вариант без запятой объективно встречается неизмеримо чаще.

Есть как минимум две ситуации с очевидно разной пунктуацией.

1. *— Всё сделал?

   **— Всё, как всегда.***
2. *— Что-нибудь изменилось?

   **— Всё как всегда.***

Немного порассуждаю.
В этих примерах вопросы для пунктуации в принципе не нужны, они лишь для понимания того, в чем разница в семантике фраз, тот самый контекст.

С первым случаем всё понятно. Там запятая незыблема.
Что касается второй ситуации, то она сложнее. Грамматика не даёт однозначного ответа, считать ли здесь "как всегда" частью сказуемого. Можно рассматривать и как вводное при односложной фразе "всё" (а почему нет?). Но, с другой стороны, семантики, т. е. понимания, это не добавит, наоборот, запутает окончательно, изменив смысл на противоположный.

Так почему не разнести эти два случая именно по разнице в значениях?
Таким образом, хотя ответы в примерах **1** и **2** в известном смысле взаимозаменяемы, я бы рекомендовал всё же использовать именно такую пунктуацию в зависимости от **смысла** ответа, а не от авторского подхода к грамматике. Уж если для ЕГЭ, то точно не мудрствовать.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, потому что "как всегда" здесь сказуемое, а его нельзя отделять от подлежащего "всё" запятой.